# Matlab read from fifo with fopen timeout

Tags: matlab, pipe

I'm working with named pipes (fifo) to communicate between python and MATLAB. The MATLAB code to read from the pipe is functional but it hangs if nothing has been written to the fifo. I would prefer it would gracefully timeout when no data is available.

If the pipe exists (in bash):

```
$ mkfifo pipe_read
```

but has no data the MATLAB open command:

```
>> fid = fopen('pipe_read', 'r');
```

hangs until data is available:

```
$ echo "test data" >> pipe_read
```

Rather than blocking forever I would like `fopen` to return a file-id that indicates an error (i.e. similar to -1 as it does when the file does not exist) if there is no data available.

Could there be a solution similar to the asynchronous reads available in the commands for writing and reading to serial instruments: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readasync.html ?

Or possibly `fopen` could be embedded into a matlab timer object that enables a timeout?

This has been asked before but without an answer:
[Matlab read from named pipe (fifo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467986/matlab-read-from-named-pipe-fifo)

Comment: I tied to reproduce the behaviour on Windows, is `fopen` already freezing? I would expect `fread` and similar to freeze. The function `readasync` is related to serial ports, unless you use java I don't know any possibility to read/write files asynchron in matlab.

Comment: @Daniel : Thanks, I'm using Mac OSX. `fopen` freezes such that I don't even get to an `fscanf` or `fread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue is not actually with Matlab's `fopen`, but the underlying `open` system call. Generally, the use of a pipe or FIFO only makes sense when there exists both a reader and a writer, and so, by default, `open(2)` will block until the other end of the FIFO has been opened as well.

I don't think it will work to embed the `fopen` call in any other Matlab object. As far as I'm aware, the only way to circumvent this is to write your own version of `fopen`, as a specialized Mex function. In this case, you can make a call to `open(2)` with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag `or`'d with whatever read/write flag you'd like. But digging around in `man 2 open`, under the `ERRORS` section, you can see that `ENXIO` is returned if "**`O_NONBLOCK` and `O_WRONLY` are set, the file is a FIFO, and no process has it open for reading**". That means you need to make sure that Python has opened the FIFO for reading *before* Matlab tries to open for writing (or vice versa).

As a final point, keep in mind that Matlab's `fopen` returns a handle to a file descriptor. Your Mex function should probably mirror that, so you can pass it around to `fread`/`fscanf`/etc without issues.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, a system call with `timeout` would do the trick.  For example:

```
timeout = 5;  % timeout in seconds
pipe = 'pipe_read';

[exit_code,str] = system(sprintf('timeout %ds cat %s', timeout, pipe));

switch(exit_code);
   case 0;    doSomething(str);   % found data
   case 124;  doTimeout();        % timedout
end
```

MacOS has `gtimeout` which I assume is similar.