# Matlab load function timeout

Tags: windows, matlab, file-processing

I would like to increase the matlab `load` command timeout as I'm accessing a resource over the network (on Windows). The default is 10s as mentioned [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/timeout.html).

How can this be achieved?

related: [Matlab read from fifo with fopen timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583670/matlab-read-from-fifo-with-fopen-timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that increasing the timeout will be hard to accomplish, but you have a way to circumvent this problem: copy the file to your local drive first, then load it. The speed will probably be the same, but you won't have to deal with the timeout.

The problem is probably caused by the fact that the mat files you are trying to load are saved using compression. This would not allow Matlab to explot the full bandwidth of your connection.

Comment: I was hoping for an undocumented part of Matlab